# Angular (animation)

Tags: анимация, css-animation, angular5

Всем привет !
Ребят есть вопрос, есть 4 кнопки, и на главной странице есть 4 блока, при каждом клике мне нужно чтобы fadeIn-ом появился первый блок а остальные прятались, потом второй и так далее.

Проблема в том что при нажатии первой кнопки, первый блок прячется на своем месте а второй блок прыгает на место первого, вот код:

```
 animations: [
    trigger('anyState', [
      state('inactive', style({
        opacity: '0.0',
        transform: 'scale(0.0)',
        display: 'none'
      })),
      state('active',   style({
        opacity: '1.0',
        transform: 'scale(1.0)',
        display: 'block'
      })),
      transition('inactive => active', animate('1000ms ease-in')),
      transition('active => inactive', animate('1000ms ease-out'))
    ]),
```

Я хочу получить результат, чтобы при клике второй кнопки, второй блок появлялся на том же месте что и первый блок, а у меня получается, что при клике на вторую кнопку первый блок плавно прячется и тогда второй прыгает на место первого.

Помогите решить эту проблему, пожалуйста!